# jquery timepicker cdnjs.cloudflare does not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, timepicker

i am using jQuery to plugin in and want to create a input field that i could select time. How come it doesn't work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

this is the js i have used. i have also used bootstrap js n jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

this is the code i used in my javascript file

this is my input field

```
<div class="form-group col-md">
    <input class="form-control" id='timepicker' type='text' name='timepicker' />
</div>
```

when i checked the console I'm getting the error that

```
jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (appointments.js:2)
    at e (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Sounds like your Jquery  ```$(document).ready(function () {``` is triggered before the script is called for the timepicker, try moving your ready event to as low down the html as you can.

Comment: okay thanks that worked, but i released it was because my bootstrap jquery and j popper links were interfering. as soon as i removed the bootstrap links it works. So as u said i put it bellow everything and it worked